# C# SQL Server - getting error creating subcategory

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

When I select the category from the comboBox, type it into the textbox and add it, there are gaps in the database. What is the reason for this? can anyone help? The photo of the database and the C# codes are below.

```
try
{
    vt.baglanti();
    komut = new SqlCommand("insert into Kategoriler(kategori, kategori_id) values(@p1, @p2)", vt.baglanti());

    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", tbAltKategori.Text);
    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", comboBox1.SelectedValue);

    komut.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("Alt Kategori Oluşturulmuştur");
    vt.baglanti().Close();
    tbAltKategori.Clear();

    dialog = MessageBox.Show(tbAltKategori.Text + "'a Ait Yeni Bir Alt Kategori Oluşturacak mısınız?", "Uyarı", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        comboboxVeri.comboboxListelemeIdAlmaSartla("id", "kategori", "Kategoriler", "kategori_id =" + comboBox1.SelectedValue, comboBox1);
                
        komut = new SqlCommand("insert into Kategoriler(kategori, kategori_id) values(@p1, @p2)", vt.baglanti());

        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", tbAltKategori.Text);
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", comboBox1.SelectedValue);

        komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    vt.baglanti().Close();
}
```

This is a method I wrote. I don't think there will be a mistake in this, but I'm still leaving the codes below.

```
comboboxVeri.comboboxListelemeIdAlmaSartla("id", "kategori", "Kategoriler", "kategori_id =" + comboBox1.SelectedValue, comboBox1)

public void comboboxListelemeIdAlmaSartla(string id, string alanAdi, string tabloAdi, string sart, ComboBox cb)
    {
        komut = new SqlCommand("select " + id + ", " + alanAdi + " from " + tabloAdi + " where " + sart, baglanti());
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(komut);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        cb.DisplayMember = alanAdi;
        cb.ValueMember = "id";
        cb.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1qEs.png) this is the image of the database.

Comment: Side point `vt.baglanti();` do not do this, do not cache the connection object. Create it when you need and dispose with `using`. Same for the command and adapter objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're clearing the textbox before the second dialogbox

```
tbAltKategori.Clear();
```

and later, if the user answers yes

```
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", tbAltKategori.Text);
```

Comment: thank you i solved this problem. but this time, when I add it, it adds it to the database twice, how can I handle this?

Comment: You are calling `komut.ExecuteNonQuery();` twice

Comment: Well I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you add the values in the beginning "komut.ExecuteNonQuery();" ~codelin 5 and then ask the user something. If the user answers "yes" you  again add the same values to the db, nothing changes.